# I can't get the Global Navigation to take my style

Tags: javascript, css

Sorry I'm sort of a noob at this stuff and have researching for a while now on the global nav and falling short. I have my global navigation working but, the code won't style. Here's my setup below:

Navigation portion in my .html file:

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <nav id="myNav">
                     <script src="js/load_essentials.js"></script>
                </nav>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
```

.js file looks like this:

```
 document.getElementById("myNav").innerHTML =
"<ul id='navLinks'>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Back</a></li>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Home</a></li>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Reviews</a></li>"
 "</ul>";
```

What am I doing incorrectly to not get it to take my styles?

Comment: why is js needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try Adding this class `'nav navbar-nav'` to your `ul` element in js file.

JS

```
document.getElementById("myNav").innerHTML =
"<ul id='navLinks' class='nav navbar-nav'>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Back</a></li>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Home</a></li>"
+ "<li><a href='blahblahblah.html'>Reviews</a></li>"
 "</ul>";
```

and load your JS using `window.onload`

Hope this Helps..

Comment: Thanks so much. It looks like i just needed the class you showed me in my JS file. You rock. Peace.